# How to turn a string field with 2 numbers in two numerical fields in the atribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a feature class with a big number of features.

In the attribute table I have a string field made from two numbers separated by an underline (e.g.: 0_1, 98_237, 31_31...). I want to create two new numerical (long integer) fields with the numbers before and after the underline (e.g.: 0_1 0 1, 98_237 98 237, 31_31 31 31...)

How can I do this using field calculator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

within the filed calculator, you can use python statement with the [split()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) function

with the first number, it will be

```
int(!field!.split("_")[0]) #creates a list of items separated by the _, and take the first item
```

and for the second number

```
int(!field!.split("_")[-1]) #creates a list of items separated by the _, and take the last item (if you have only 2 items, you could also use 1(= the second item in Python index)
```

int() is not necessary if you have an integer field as output, but I prefer to use it so that the conversion is obvious. If your number are floating points, use "float()" instead of "int()"

Comment: Thanks. But it didn't worked here. I put exactly: int(!ID_APR!.split()[0]); ID_APR is the field I want to split. Got the error 000539: Error running expression: int (u "0_2".split()[0]). The complete error message: Messages
Executing: CalculateField RJ_Linhas300_Protegidas FID1 int(!ID_APR!.split()[0]) PYTHON_9.3 #
Start Time: Fri Jan 04 10:17:02 2019
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: int(u"0_2".split()[0]) 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0_2'
Failed to execute (CalculateField).

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to type the _ on which you want to split. by default it is split by a space